# For which odd primes p is 13 a square modulo p?

Tags: number-theory

For which odd primes p is 13 a square modulo p?

I've seen a similar example using 10 but still have some difficulty solving this one.

Can anyone please help me solve this? 
Any comments are welcome.

Comment: Hint: use quadratic reciprocity.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint.** The following theorem solves your problem pretty much immediately.

> **Theorem** (Quadratic Reciprocity)**.** Let $p,q$ be distinct odd primes, then $$\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)=(-1)^{(p-1)(q-1)/4}$$ where $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)$ is the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).

Your problem can be restated as: for which primes $p$ is $\left(\frac{11}{p}\right)=1$? To get the answer, simply substitute into the theorem above with $q=11$ and see what comes out. I'll leave the rest to you.